# How to reference a list of types representing existing records?

Tags: graphql

Suppose I have two types, `User` and `Permission`, e.g.

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!
  email: String!
  permissions: [Permission!]
}

type Permission {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

`User` has `permissions` field, which contains a list of associated `Permission` type records.

How do I structure a mutation query that updates which permissions user has?

Answer (score 1):

I have simply used a list of `ID` type for the `permissions` parameter in the mutation

I have set `permissions` parameter to a list of [`GraphQLID`](http://graphql.org/docs/api-reference-type-system/#graphqlid).

```
type Mutation {
  updateUser (
    id: ID!
    email: String
    password: String
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    # List of Permission IDs
    permissions: [ID!]
  ): User
}
```

The problem with this approach is that this does not define relation between `Permission` type and `ID`. Therefore, I have added "List of Permission IDs" comment.

Another approach would be to create a dedicated input type, e.g.

```
input PermissionInput {
    id: ID!
}
```

And use that in instead of `ID` in the `updateUser` permissions parameter. However, this does not solve the reference issue.

Comment: I'd just go with the first one of these, i've done similar and its absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I can't add just a comment, but we solve the problem in the same way - but to ensure clarity and consistency of the shape of the data, we use specific id fields. I.e. we would define the input like this:

```
type Mutation {
  updateUser (
    id: ID!
    email: String
    password: String
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    permissionIds: [ID!]
  ): User
}
```

Pretty basic difference, but it clearly differentiates the input from the output, each field name is intuitive and there isn't much overhead.

Comment: Thats exactly what I have gone with at the end. :-)